# export SSRS Adjacent groups to different excel tabs

Tags: ssrs-2008, export-to-excel

I have a ssrs Tablix, i have two adjacent groups , example group 1 : Managers and group 2 : Manager Details . they both are separate adjacent groups. client wants to export them to an excel with two tabs Managers, Details . first sheet should get all data from group 1 and second sheet should get all data from group 2.

can anyone advice.

Comment: Typically you would put each tablix in a rectangle, then set "page break after" on  the first rectangle's properties and set the pagename property to whatever yo want. Having said that, I'm not sure is SSRS 2008 supports this, I "think" it was only introduced in 2008R2

Answer (score 0):

1. create two additional rows in dataset with static values of xyz, abc.
2. for first group , group by xyz column and second group , group by abc column.
3. in the report make a page based on xyz, abc groups and the result is achieved automatically.